# Why do my Bootstrap columns wrap in an uneven manner?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I had a problem with a row in bootstrap that wraps totally wrong.

On desktop screens, there are 4 boxes in a row shown perfectly.
On smaller screens, it changes to 2 boxes in a row. Perfect. But if the size of the left box in row 1 is bigger because of more text in it, than the third box disappears in row 2 and will display in row 3.

If box 2 has a bigger size than box 1, it wraps around totally ok.

I add you two images of the problem and also a light version of the code

This is the picture of the failure

[image: failure_image]

This is the picture of the right execution i wanted to have also on the left boxes

[image: right_image]

And this is the code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="features-grids">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature1">
            <a href="sites/story.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Unsere Story</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="feature2">
            <p>Hier findet ihr einen Rückblick auf unser gemeinsames Leben</p>                                  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature1">
            <a href="sites/galerie_hochzeit.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Galerie</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="feature2">
            <p>Hier findet ihr Fotos - Von vor und nach der Hochzeit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature1">
            <a href="sites/hochzeit.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Wichtigste Infos</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="feature2">
            <p>Hier findet ihr alle wichtigen Infos zu unserem großen Tag</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature1">
            <a href="sites/wunschliste.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Wunschliste</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="feature2">
            <p>Hier findet ihr die nützlichsten Geschenkideen für uns</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
</div>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman, there's no indication here that custom CSS is a factor.

Comment: Rene, the lesson here is to always compare your markup carefully to the Bootstrap demo markup. You're missing a row element, as muhaymin khan points out below.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: I'm sorry for all my faults i did with the question :-D
Thanks all for your help. muhaymin khan was right. The missing row element was the term.

Answer (score 1):

First, you missed the div with the class `row` between your `col-md-3` and `features-grids` div. Also add `col-sm-6` with all the `col-md-3` it will hopefully work fine.

Check this out:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="features-grids">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature1">
            <a href="sites/story.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Unsere Story</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="feature2">
            <p>Hier findet ihr einen Rückblick auf unser gemeinsames Leben</p>                                  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature1">
            <a href="sites/galerie_hochzeit.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Galerie</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="feature2">
            <p>Hier findet ihr Fotos - Von vor und nach der Hochzeit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature1">
            <a href="sites/hochzeit.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Wichtigste Infos</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="feature2">
            <p>Hier findet ihr alle wichtigen Infos zu unserem großen Tag</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature1">
            <a href="sites/wunschliste.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Wunschliste</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="feature2">
            <p>Hier findet ihr die nützlichsten Geschenkideen für uns</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Chances are the `row` class can be added to the `features-grids` element.

Comment: Thanks man! I was sitting here for hours.. I tried also the col-sm-6 variant before - but it doesnt work. I think of the missing row element.